# Apache Lucene Indexer Search

Tags: java, apache, indexing, lucene

I am using Apache lucene Indexer Search to search text, But while using this I have following problem.

```
If I indexed word "Steve" and if I want to search that word then If 
I search using following possibilities like *S*, *St* , *Ste*, *Stev* 
then It gives correct result.

But If I search using whole word like *Steve* then Its giving zero hits.
```

For.e.g. My code is as follows.

```
--------call to Search ------  
TopDocs foundDocs2 = searchByFirstName("*Steve*", searcher);
-------------------------------------------------------------
private static TopDocs searchByFirstName(String firstName, IndexSearcher searcher) throws Exception
{

        MultiFieldQueryParser mqp = new MultiFieldQueryParser(new String[]{"firstName"}, new StandardAnalyzer());
        mqp.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
        Query q =mqp.parse(firstName);
        TopDocs hits = searcher.search(q, 10);
        return hits;
}
```

If I Search with whole word its returning zero hits.

my Index writer is as follows.

```
writer = getIndexWriter();
List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<>();
Document document1 = createDocument(1, "Steve", "Richard", "richard.com");
writer.addDocument(document1);
writer.commit();



 private static Document createDocument(Integer id, String firstName, String lastName, String website)
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        document.add(new StringField("id", id.toString() , Field.Store.YES));
        document.add(new TextField("firstName", firstName , Field.Store.YES));
        document.add(new TextField("lastName", lastName , Field.Store.YES));
        document.add(new TextField("website", website , Field.Store.YES));
        return document;
    }


 private static IndexWriter createWriter() throws IOException
    {
        FSDirectory dir = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(INDEX_DIR).toFile());
        IndexWriterConfig config = new    IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_44,new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_44));
        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, config);
        return writer;
    }
```

Comment: Don't know which version you are using, but it should work if the index happened on first name. Please post version and how you are indexing the words/content.

Comment: I am using Version 4.10.3

Comment: As i mentioned post your Indexwriter

Comment: @mallikarjun I have added my sample code for Indexwriter

Comment: Everything looks good, It should get the record if the code is everything you have mentioned. Use [luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/) to view the records are created or not after IndexWriter.

Comment: @mallikarjun , How to use it...I am unable to open indexer files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173616/discussion-between-mallikarjun-and-onkarg).